# List<T>.RemoveAll as parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, task-parallel-library, generic-collections

I would like to known an alternative to do a `toProcess.RemoveAll`, but in parallel. Today my code like my exemplo is working well, but in sequencial, and I'd like to be in paralle.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ParallelTest
{
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<VerifySomethingFromInternet> foo = new List<VerifySomethingFromInternet>();
            foo.Add(new VerifySomethingFromInternet(@"id1", true));
            foo.Add(new VerifySomethingFromInternet(@"id2", false));
            foo.Add(new VerifySomethingFromInternet(@"id3", true));
            foo.Add(new VerifySomethingFromInternet(@"id4", false));
            foo.Add(new VerifySomethingFromInternet(@"id5", true));
            foo.Add(new VerifySomethingFromInternet(@"id6", false));

            DoSomethingFromIntert bar = new DoSomethingFromIntert();

            bar.DoesWork(foo);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class DoSomethingFromIntert
    {
        bool RemoveIFTrueFromInternet(VerifySomethingFromInternet vsfi)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Identification : {0} - Thread : {1}", vsfi.Identification, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            // Do some blocking work at internet
            return vsfi.IsRemovable;
        }

        public void DoesWork(List<VerifySomethingFromInternet> toProcess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("total : {0}", toProcess.Count));
            //Remove all true return
            toProcess.RemoveAll(f => this.RemoveIFTrueFromInternet(f));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("total : {0}", toProcess.Count));
        }
    }
    public class VerifySomethingFromInternet
    {
        public VerifySomethingFromInternet(string id, bool remove)
        {
            this.Identification = id;
            this.IsRemovable = remove;
        }
        public string Identification { get; set; }
        public bool IsRemovable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why?  Are you sure this is the most time-consuming part? Seems unlikely.

Comment: Patrick has just answered. Perhaps `BlockingCollection` is your choice here. it is a type of producer consumer type of collection

Comment: You could use parallel LINQ to get the list of removable items, construct a hashset from that, and finally use list.removeall with hashset.contains for actual removal

Comment: You could run parallel.foreach(remove...) followeed by list.removeall(x=>x.isremovable)

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for you consideration but it is. In that part we are consuming a slow webservices.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm refactoring to that way, but I would make sure that is a good (or the best way). That's the problem when you are the unique C# developer at your company, it's hard to share question about the best away to do something advantage.

Comment: I'm not fond of mutating `vsfi` to set a flag since I prefer a functional programming style where I avoid side effects/mutations. I'd probably remove the flag and go with my first approach.

Comment: @SolliMoreiraHonorio - There is no way in the known universe that the removal of items from the list is the slow part in your code that retrieves data from the internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var newList = toProcess.AsParallel ()
               .Where (f => !this.RemoveIFTrueFromInternet(f))
               .ToList ();

toProcess = newList;
```

Probably this answers your question, but I'm not sure that it's really faster. Try and measure.

Note that this may change the order of the elements in the list. If you care about order, add `AsOrdered` after `AsParallel`. (Thanks to weston for the [implicit] hint).

Comment: Sorry John, thought you'd arrived at this after my answer, cause the answer appeared at the top.

Comment: Deleted mine, added nothing. Thanks for the `Enumerable.Range` tip, I like that.

Answer (score 4):

`List<T>` isn't thread safe so there is no way to do this in parallel with this type of list.

You can use thread safe `ConcurrentBag` instead, but that one doesn't have a `RemoveAll` method, obviously.

You can also convert the list to an array, edit that one, and pass it to list again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to restructure your code a bit

I used `BlockingCollection` to implement a producer consumer scenario

this is not removing in parallel but it may solve your problem by processing them in parallel, give it a try you may love it

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomethingFromIntert bar = new DoSomethingFromIntert();  
        bar.Verify(@"id1", true);
        bar.Verify(@"id2", false);
        bar.Verify(@"id3", true);
        bar.Verify(@"id4", false);
        bar.Verify(@"id5", true);
        bar.Verify(@"id6", false);

        bar.Complete();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class DoSomethingFromIntert
{
    BlockingCollection<VerifySomethingFromInternet> toProcess = new BlockingCollection<VerifySomethingFromInternet>();
    ConcurrentBag<VerifySomethingFromInternet> workinglist = new ConcurrentBag<VerifySomethingFromInternet>();

    public DoSomethingFromIntert()
    {
        //init four consumers you may choose as many as you want
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoesWork);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoesWork);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoesWork);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoesWork);
    }

    public void Verify(string param, bool flag)
    {
        //add to the processing list
        toProcess.TryAdd(new VerifySomethingFromInternet(param, flag));
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        //mark producer as complete and let the threads exit when finished verifying
        toProcess.CompleteAdding();
    }

    bool RemoveIFTrueFromInternet(VerifySomethingFromInternet vsfi)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Identification : {0} - Thread : {1}", vsfi.Identification, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        // Do some blocking work at internet
        return vsfi.IsRemovable;
    }

    private void DoesWork(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("total : {0}", toProcess.Count));
        foreach (var item in toProcess.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            //do work
            if (!RemoveIFTrueFromInternet(item))
            {
                //add to list if working
                workinglist.TryAdd(item);
            }
            //no need to remove as it is removed from the list automatically
        }
        //this line will only reach after toProcess.CompleteAdding() and when items are consumed(verified)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("total : {0}", toProcess.Count));
    }
}
```

in short it will start verifying the items as soon as you add them and will keep the successful items in a separate list

**Edit**

as the foreach loop for `GetConsumingEnumerable()` does not end by default it keep waiting for the next element forever until `CompleteAdding()` is called. so I added `Complete()` method in the wrapper class to finish the verification loop once we have pushed all the elements.

the idea is to keep adding the verification elements to the class and let the consumer loop verify each of them in parallel and once you are done will all of the elements call Complete() to know the consumers that there are no more elements to be added so they can terminate the foreach loop once the list is empty.

in your code the removal of the element is not the actual issue of performance but the synchronous loop of the verification process if the hot spot. removing from list a just a cost of few ms however the expensive part of the code is the `blocking work at internet` so if we can make it parallel we are able to cut some of the precious time.

be careful with the number of consumers threads you initialize, however I used thread pool but still may affect performance if excessively used. so decide a number based on the machine capability eg. number or cores / processors

more about [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312)